# Retrieving the Post data after the ajax request if a user decides to go back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Description: Please check the code it will make more sense,

I have successfully created a function that will do the following:
1. It will look for the form with class="ajax"
2. It will look for the attributes (action, method, name)
3. The form on index.php have two name attribute they are fname and lname
4. If the name fields are not empty then it will make a post request from the index.php file to ajaxphp/save.php where the value of fname and lname are hidden from the form and the form has another input field called email
5. And again when the form is submitted from ajaxphp/save.php then it will again make the post request to ../home.php where all the post variable are seen.
6. I have also added a new button on ./ajaxphp/save.php  Go back

Problem:
If a user fills up the form at index.php and goes to ajaxphp/save.php and decides to go back again to the index.php by clicking the go back button, I do I populate the fname and lname field the user had already inserted and submitted.

Source Code: https://github.com/kiranbhattarai/Global-Ajax.git
//change the ./classes/config.php and it will work perfectly on your localhost.

I have already tried inserting the post request from index.php into the database and pulling it back again when they click the Go back button. But i am looking for a way to do it ajax, without the need of database.

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit',function () {

    var that = $(this),         //$this is a reference to the calling object of forms with class .ajax
    url = that.attr('action'),  //represents the action specified on the form
    type = that.attr('method'), //reperesents the method specified on the form

    data = [];                  //creating an array to store the values

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){  //find() function finds all the value with the name attribute and each() function loops through all the inputs files that has name attribure
        var that = $(this),         //$this is a reference to the calling object of forms input name attr
        name = that.attr('name'),  //assigning name of the input field to a variable name
        value = that.val();        //assigning the value input filed to a variable value
        data[name] = value;        //assigning the respective name value pair
    });

  //  console.log(data);

if(data['fname']=='' || data['lname']==''){   //checking if the fields are empty or not
      alert('Please fill all the fields');
}
else{
    $.ajax({                //Submitting the ajax request
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }

    });
}
    return false;  
});
```

I have tried my best to document the code by properly explaining all the functions. They are on git hub please check the link above.

Comment: You can define and access Global variables in the current Window : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) to save the `data` in browser.

```
//for reading
var data;
if (localStorage.getItem('data')) {
  data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  // do actions
  // console.log(data['fname'])
}

// for writing
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
      // ...
      else {
        var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data);
        localStorage.setItem('data', jsonStr);
        $.ajax({
        //...
```